# How to define variable value as variable?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to define an object value as a new variable. How can I achieve this?
Here's an example:

```
var msg = '{
  "fname": {
    "req": "first name required"
  },
  "email": {
    "req": "email is required",
    "validate": "provide valid email"
  }
}';
var obj = JSON.parse(msg);

console.log(msg.fname.req) // logs "first name required", that's fine
```

This is what I tried so far:

```
 new_fname = 'fname'
 console.log(msg.new_fname.req) // this throws an error ("req is not defined")
```

How can I declare the `new_fname` value as a new variable?

Comment: `msg[new_fname].req`

Comment: thanks its work for me....